# PathVariable binding to java object not working with spring-webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Below code used to work fine:

Model Class:

```
public class Employee {
  private String id;   // used as path-variable
  private String temp; // used as query parameter
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(
      path = "/employee/{id}",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Mono<EmployeeDetails> getEmployee(Employee emp) {
    System.out.println(emp.getId()+ ", "+emp.getTemp());
}
```

Above used to work fine when I hit above with URL
http://localhost:8080/employee/**100?temp=1234**

Then there was some common jar changes in project(which included some webflux related jars) and now path variable "id" is no longer mapping in Employee object.
What is that I'm missing here ?

Comment: Why not simply use `@Pathvariable` annotation to map your id?

Comment: @akuma8 This is not regarding finding other solution, I know it. Question is why it stopped working and what is the solution to make it working again this way.